# Web link parser that hunts for a specific string

Tags: performance, csv, vb.net

This handles a parsing system to look at every users profile page and determine their job classification based on the class of a div element. I noticed that the class was always consistent on specific types of employees so I created this script to weed them out from other classes so I can have a pure list of employees for searches. What I have noticed is the script can handle 2 - 3 per second, and there are 30,000 of them to sort. This takes a few hours so I was forced to open several instances of the same program to cut the time down.

What might I do to make this code more efficient and less time consuming? I have been looking for solutions, but none that point out directly the flaws of my coding practice.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInput.Click

    Dim myFileDlog As New OpenFileDialog()

    Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()

    'look for files in the default folder
    myFileDlog.InitialDirectory = appPath.ToString & "\Reports"

    'specifies what type of data files to look for
    myFileDlog.Filter = "Data Files (*.csv)|*.csv"

    'specifies which data type is focused on start up
    myFileDlog.FilterIndex = 1

    'Gets or sets a value indicating whether the dialog box restores the current directory before closing.
    myFileDlog.RestoreDirectory = True

    'seperates message outputs for files found or not found
    If myFileDlog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If Dir(myFileDlog.FileName) <> "" Then
            'Adds the file directory to the text box
            tbInput.Text = myFileDlog.FileName
            myFileDlog.FileName = Nothing
            myFileDlog.Dispose()
        Else
            MsgBox("File Not Found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnOutput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOutput.Click

    Dim SaveFile As New SaveFileDialog()

    Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()

    'look for files in the c drive
    SaveFile.InitialDirectory = appPath.ToString & "\Reports"

    SaveFile.Filter = "Data Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    SaveFile.Title = "Output"

    If SaveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim Write As New System.IO.StreamWriter(SaveFile.FileName)
        tbOutput.Text = SaveFile.FileName
        SaveFile.FileName = Nothing
        Write.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub

Public Function CheckAddress(ByVal URL As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

    FileOpen(1, "orange_emps.csv", OpenMode.Output)
FileOpen(2, tbOutput.Text, OpenMode.Output)

' ------- User Table ----------->
Dim userL As New List(Of String)

'----------------------------- Read the User Table to Lists --------------------------------->
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(tbInput.Text)
    MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    Dim currentRow As String()
    Dim rowP As Integer = 1

    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            Dim cellP As Integer = 0

            For Each currentField As String In currentRow

                If rowP > 0 Then

                    If Not currentField = "" Then
                        userL.Add(currentField.Replace("""", ""))
                    End If

                    cellP += 1

                End If

            Next

        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException

            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")

        End Try

        rowP += 1

    End While

End Using '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Dim userLAR As String() = userL.ToArray

Dim orangeL As New List(Of String)

Dim curLN As String ' ------- the current user in the row --->

Dim jobCount = IO.File.ReadAllLines(tbInput.Text).Length

Dim jobPer As Double = 0

Dim pBar As Integer = 1

progBar.Maximum = userLAR.Length

    Dim pBarScale As Decimal = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To userLAR.Length - 1

        curLN = userLAR(i).ToString

        ' Specify the URL to receive the request. 
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://empDB.mysite.com/emps/" & curLN), HttpWebRequest)

        ' Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4

        ' Set credentials to use for this request.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        ' Get the stream associated with the response. 
        Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

        ' Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.  
        Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)

        ' Store contents in this String.
        Dim line As String

        Dim newURL As String = "https://empDB.mysite.com/emps/" & curLN

        Dim sourceCheck As Boolean = CheckAddress(newURL)

        ' ---- make sure the employee still exists in db -->
        If sourceCheck = True Then

            ' Read first line.
            line = readStream.ReadLine

            Dim lineCount As Integer = 0

            ' Loop over each line in file, While list is Not Nothing.
            Do While (lineCount < 500)

                If lineCount > 400 Then

                jobPer = Format(((i + 1) / userLAR.Length) * 100, "0.00")

                    labProg.Text = "Progress: " & i + 1 & " of " & userLAR.Length
                labPer.Text = jobPer & "%"
                Me.Text = "PhoneTool Scraper " & jobPer & "%"

                If line.Contains("orange-frame") Then
                   orangeL.Add(userLAR(i))
                   lineCount = 500
                End If

                End If

                ' Read in the next line.
                line = readStream.ReadLine
                lineCount += 1

            Loop

        End If

        response.Close()
        readStream.Close()

        If progBar.Value + pBar < progBar.Maximum Then
            progBar.Value += pBar
        End If


        Application.DoEvents()

    Next

    PrintLine(1, "----- Orange Emps -----")

    For Each orange In orangeL
        PrintLine(1, orange)
    Next

    PrintLine(1, "")
    PrintLine(1, orangeL.Count)


progBar.Value = userLAR.Length

    FileClose(1)
    FileClose(2)

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "orange_emps.csv"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Process.Start(FILE_NAME)
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

**Quick definitions:**

`userL` = a list of employees pre-compiled for the check

`userLAR` = an array created from `userL`

`orangeL` = the list of employees pulled from the report sheet

The reason I start the `lineCount` `If` statement at 400 and end at 500 is because I believed it would save time not doing comparisons until the range that the values show up in. I don't believe this was correct.

`Application.DoEvents()` is being used only to update the users with the current progress of the report as well as the current count of employees filtered.

Here is a sample of the web link's html lines that are read by the loop:

```
<option value="Country">Country</option>    
<option value="City">City</option></select> 
</i>    
</button>   
</div>  
</form> 
</div>  
</div>  
</div>  
</nav>  

<div class='alert-wrapper'> 
</div>  
<div id='content'>  
<!-- / Ring Ring Ring Ring Ring Ring Ring -->   

<div class='container-fluid'>   
<div class='row-fluid emp'> 
<div class='employee-frame'>    
<div class='no-frame-border pull-right worker-frame orange-frame'>  
<div class='hole-wrapper'>  
<div class='hole'></div>    
</div>  
<div class='user'>  
johndoe 
</div>  
<div class='row-fluid picture-frame'>   
<div class='photo'> 
<img alt="John Doe" id="frame-image" src="./?uid=johndoe" style="" />   
</div>  
</div>  
<div class='name'>  
<p> 
<strong>    
John    
</strong>   
</p>    
<p> 
Doe 
</p>    
</div>  
</div>  

</div>  
<div class='emp-info'>  
<div class='row-fluid'> 
<p class='name'>    
John Doe    
<div class='prefname'>  
</div>  
</p>    
<p class='title'>   
House Cleaning
<a href="#">External (8725)</a> 
</p>    
<div class='row-fluid'> 
<p class='email'>   
<a href="mailto:johndoe@mysite.com">johndoe@mysite.com</a>  
</p>    
<p class='display-options pull-right'>  
<i class="icon-cog icon-large muted"></i>   
<a href="#display-options-modal" class="muted" data-toggle="modal">Display       options</a>    
<div class='modal hide fade' id='display-options-modal' role='dialog'     tabindex='-1'>    
<div class='modal-dialog'>  
<div class='modal-content'> 
<div class='modal-header header-name colored-header'>   
Display Options 
<a href="#" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-remove- symble"></i></a> 
</div>  
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/johndoe/update_user_pref"  class="formtastic user_pref" id="edit_user_pref_123456789" method="post"  novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input  name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x1234;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden"  value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden"  value="4asdfeadfagtadgfasdg5ad=" /></div><ul class='nav nav-tabs'>  
<li class='active'> 
<a href="#tab-main" data-toggle="tab">Main</a>  
</li>   
<li>    
<a href="#tab-tree" data-toggle="tab">Chart Tab</a> 
</li>   
</ul>   
<div class='tab-content'>   
<div class='tab-pane active' id='tab-main'> 
<div class='modal-header title-header'> 
Frame Image 
</div>  
<div class='row-fluid'> 
<div class='span12'>    
<li class="checkbox boolean input optional"  id="user_pref_profile_show_frame_wrap_input"><input  name="user_pref[profile_show_frame_wrap]" type="hidden" value="0" /><label  class="" for="user_pref_profile_show_frame_wrap"><input checked="checked"  id="user_pref_profile_show_frame_wrap" name="user_pref[profile_show_frame_wrap]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />Show Frame Wraps (indicates tenure)</label>  

</li>   
<li class="checkbox boolean input optional"  id="user_pref_profile_show_custom_image_input"><input  name="user_pref[profile_show_custom_iamge]" type="hidden" value="0" /><label class="" for="user_pref_profile_show_custom_iamge"><input checked="checked"  id="user_pref_profile_show_custom_image"  name="user_pref[profile_show_custom_image]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Show  custom (user-uploaded) Image by default</label>   

 </li>  
 </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class='modal-header title-header'>    
info block  
 </div> 
<div class='row-fluid'> 
<div class='span6'> 
<li class="checkbox boolean input optional"  id="user_pref_profile_show_local_input"><input  name="user_pref[profile_show_local]" type="hidden" value="0" /><label class=""  for="user_pref_profile_show_local"><input checked="checked"      id="user_pref_profile_show_local" name="user_pref[profile_show_local]"       type="checkbox" value="1" /> Show Area (e.g.  Building 1 - My Name)</label>
```

This is just a sample of the web link page. The code is not rellevent other than for the parsing purpoes. It is looking for a line containing `orange-frame` and adding the `userL` name to a `orangeL`.

Comment: Can you post the entire method body? And if you do, please include the `CheckAddress` method. I recommend you read this blog post while waiting for reviews :) [Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx)

Comment: Complete code added!

Comment: It would be great if you could add some sample data.

Comment: Let me work on that. That might take a bit of time on that one. I will have to do some work on that one, because I will have to change the names of the data as it is company confidential information. I have already changed the web link and names for that reason. The file has roughly 30k lines in a single column of logins. I am sure I can produce something. :)

Comment: I added the web link page html as a reference for what the parser is actually handling.

Comment: I don't know if you are doing this with the other people concent or looking at their robots.txt. But I would split this into two process, one that downloads the page on the HD (this should be multi-threaded). And an other process that parses the files. You'll only need to download once and then be able to parse as many time as you want. If it's a small website, they'll hate you if you take a lot of their bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your Button Click Event (`btnOutput_Click`) you should be using a using statement for your writer here:

> ```
> Dim Write As New System.IO.StreamWriter(SaveFile.FileName)
> tbOutput.Text = SaveFile.FileName
> SaveFile.FileName = Nothing
> Write.Dispose()
> ```

like this

```
Using Write As New System.IO.StreamWriter(SaveFile.FileName)
    tbOutput.Text = SaveFile.FileName
    SaveFile.FileName = Nothing
End Using
```

it will make sure that no matter what, once the scope leaves that using block that the StreamWriter is disposed of, which is very important.  Anything that implements the IDisposable interface should be used in conjunction with a using block.